# Library to edit Traktor hot cues

Tags: library, music, mp3

I am looking for a library that can:

- view Traktor hot cues when given an MP3 as input.

If possible, can:

- support FLAC
- edit, add, remove Traktor hot cues

I would prefer Python/C++/Java/R/MATLAB, and on Windows 7 if OS-dependent.